# Other ways to bind HTML to JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, runtime

I know two ways to bind HTML to client-side JavaScript code and stay a kind of object-oriented:

1. Use a lot of IDs (or special CSS class names, or some other distinct HTML attributes) in HTML and do a "harvest" in JS initialization method (or request each DOM object each time, right before use);
2. Do not write HTML at all. Construct an element at runtime, in initializer, and remember a reference to DOM object (or jQuery object) in a variable.

Are there some other ways that allow to use design-time phase (writhing HTML) which is much more convenient than doing all the work at runtime, and at the same time do not use a lot of identifiers of any kind having to maintain their uniqueness?

Comment: You don't neccessarely have to have identifiers on all the elements, you can traverse the DOM in many ways

Comment: That's where the wonderful AngularJS and its magical 2-way data binding comes into action :)

Comment: I agree on AngularJS, beautiful framework for 2 way data binding. Definitely worth the look! https://angularjs.org/

Comment: @paul yes my choice also AngularJS . so please try with that.

Comment: @adeneo: Yes, I know that I can for example search for n-th element in k-th block, but what if they change their positions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[AngularJS](https://angularjs.org/) is the framework you want to use for 2-way data binding.

I used AngularJS for multiple projects now, combined with nodeJS, and I never looked back at jQuery, you keep your code clean with the MVC pattern and manipulating the DOM is made easy and clear.

Example for 2 way data binding:

**HTML**

```
<p>{{elementText}}</p>
<input type="text" ng-model="item.value" />
```

**JavaScript/Controller**

```
$scope.item = {
    value: ''
};        

$scope.elementText = "The text you want to display";
console.log($scope.item.value); //Directly get your values from the scope.
```

Want to assign values to `<select>` boxes or fill `<table>`'s using JSON data? No problem, AngularJS got you covered.

Interesting AngularJS features:

- [ng-model](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel)
- [ng-repeat](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat)
- [Animations](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/animations)
- [Custom directives](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive)

I hope this will help you!

Comment: @Paul - Watch this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TRrL5j3MIvo - And that's the best course ever on Angular : https://www.udemy.com/learn-angularjs

Comment: Your example is weird... `item` is undefined, `elementText` is static... What's the point? I would go for `<p>{{elementText}}</p>
<input type="text" ng-model="elementText" />` and nothing else.

Comment: @JeremyThille You are right, my bad, never defined item.. I wanted to make the example to show the usage of JSON objects in your scope. I will edit.

Comment: Is Angular.js the only way?

Comment: @Paul No. You could also have a look at DHTMLX - http://dhtmlx.com/ , but I don't see much reason not to choose for AngularJS, I think we need more info about what your final goal is to go in depth.